# Memory leak detection under Windows for GNU C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, open-source, memory-leaks

What memory leak detection tools are available for use with open source C/C++ on Windows?

Comment: I use deleaker - power tool. But it's proprietary)

Comment: This question is very specific. It asks about something not easy to find. It's also very useful. It's more about specific knowledge than opinion. I think locking this takes away from value of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [mem (revised)](http://teaching.idallen.com/c_programming/mem/) package is an effective and straightforward tool to detect memory buffer overflows, underflows, leaks, double-deletion, and dangling references.

[Original link to c.snippets.org, now invalid.](http://c.snippets.org/browser.php?sect=37#37)

Comment: Snippets.org no longer exists as a host for mem.txt; it is now a deals website.  I located a modified copy of Mem here for now : http://teaching.idallen.com/c_programming/mem/

Answer (score 7):

I've been using VLD ([Visual Leak Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx)) for some times, it works nicely for good code, for more complex code; it's not perfect.

Comment: Newer version at author's home page: http://dmoulding.googlepages.com/vld

Comment: From the documentation: It is designed specifically for use with Visual C++, and it depends on heap debugging functions found only in Microsoft's C runtime library.

Comment: @RobKam: The source code is readily available for Microsoft's C runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg is always a good choice for any program open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

LeakDiag.  Quite hard to find nowadays, but available [here](http://ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/PSS/Tools/Developer%20Support%20Tools/).  You might also like to get LDGrapher, available in the same place.