# Troubleshoot C++ program memory usage issue

Tags: c++, memory-management, instruments

I am authoring a C++ program and find it consumes too much memory. I would like to know which part of the program consumes the most number of memory, ideally, I would like to know how much percentage of memory are consumed by what kind of C++ objects the program is using at a particular moment.

In Java, I know tools like Eclipse Memory Analyzer (https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) which could take a heap dump and show/visualize such memory usage, and I wonder if this can be done for a C++ program. For example, I expect to use a tool/approach letting me know a particular `vector<shared_ptr<MyObject>>` is holding 30% of the memory.

Note:

- I develop the program mainly on macOS (compile using Apple Clang), so it will be better if the approach works on macOS. But I do deploy to Linux as well (compile using gcc) so approaches/tools on Linux is okay.
- I tried using Apple's [Intruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(software)) for such purpose, but so far I can only use it to find memory allocation issue. I have no idea how to figure out the memory consumption of the program at a particular moment (the memory consumption should be related with C++ objects in the program so that I can do some action to reduce it accordingly).

Comment: It's been a while since I used it so I can't help you with the details, but can't Instruments record each allocation made by your application along with a stack trace that shows where you made it from?  That's my (hazy) recollection, anyway.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes it can, but the problem is lots of allocations are temporary. Memory is allocated and then released, and I don't care about those temporary allocations. I wonder which part occupies the most of memory at a particular moment.

Comment: I recommend reviewing your code and eliminating all unnecessary memory allocations and try running again.

Comment: The use of `shared_ptr` implies that you don't have a clear "owner" of your `MyObject`s. How do you ensure their timely cleanup? Or do all of these objects live for the duration of your program? What size of memory is "too much"? What's the size of the single object? How many of them do you expect to have? Do the numbers add up?

Comment: @VladFeinstein `vector<shared_ptr>` is just an example, I am actually not certain which part consumes the memory currently. `What size of memory is "too much"?` The program consumes some external data, and the memory usage is 5x times more than the original data, so I think it may be "too much". I am not certain about the detailed usage, and that is why I am looking for tools/approaches to figure it out.

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410160/alternative-to-valgrind-memcheck-for-finding-leaks-on-linux/64097870#64097870. Your code may have leaks, or memory fragment, or bugs that consume too much memory.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin thanks for the reply. I am not trying to figure out leaks. My program is expected to hold some data in the memory, but current data structure may make the memory consumption too much, and I am looking for better data structure for replacing it, but I need to figure out which part is the most memory demanding data structure

Comment: @nybon Then you need some memory profilers, tcmalloc would be your friend, but it will downgrade the performance a lot (up to 50 times slower if you have heavy threads usage). So if your program is an online service, we may need to consider copying part of the network request to make sure that the sever would not be overload.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find an easy way to visualize/summarize each part of my program's memory yet. So far, the best tool/approach that I found is Apple's Instruments (if you are on macOS).

By using Instruments, you can use `Allocations` profiling template. When using this profiling template, you can choose `File` ==> `Recording Options` ==> Check `Discard events for freed memory` option

[image]

And you will be able to figure out the un-free memory (aka. the data that are still in the memory) during allocation recording. If you have your program's debug symbol loaded, you can see which function leads to this result.

[image]

Although this doesn't address all the issues, it does help to identify part of the problem.