# Is there a freeware utility out there to monitor a c++ application for memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I am verifying an application coded in c++ with memory leak and need a utility (freeware) I can easily run to detect where it is ocurring. any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

On the following platforms,

```
x86/Linux: support is mature and almost complete.
AMD64/Linux: support is mature and almost complete.
PPC32/Linux: support is new but fairly complete.
PPC64/Linux: support is new but fairly complete.
x86/Darwin (Mac OS X): support is new.
AMD64/Darwin (Mac OS X): not officially supported, but probably works.
```

I'd recommend [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html)

If you're using Visual Studio, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(VS.80).aspx) has some info.

If you're using Windows, and not Visual Studio, then [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283726/memory-leak-detection-under-windows-for-gnu-c-c) has a lot of suggestions - and then this question should be closed :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on OS you are using. On Windows there is a very good free tool — the [user-mode dump heap (UMDH) utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343).

Comment: Since I discovered this utility on SO, it is my first port of call.  I use it before boundschecker and purify.  I find it of most use in transactional parts of the system.  EG take snap shot, perform transaction, take a new snap shot and compare to find leaks in the transaction processing.  For this work flow there is no better tool on windows.